# Unlocking Admin Account for Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex

I'm trying to unlock my Admin Account for Oracle but I can't seem to get it to work.
This is the code I used: Running in sqldeveloper

*********************************Alter*****************************

```
ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = Schema from DB;

COLUMN user_id Format 99999999999999999
COLUMN first_name FORMAT A20
COLUMN last_name FORMAT A20
COLUMN default_schema FORMAT A30

SELECT user_id,
       first_name,
       last_name,
       default_schema
FROM   wwv_flow_fnd_user
WHERE  user_name = 'ADMIN'
ORDER BY last_update_date DESC;
```

*********************************UPDATE USER*****************************

```
UPDATE wwv_flow_fnd_user
SET    web_password = '**My Password**'  
WHERE  user_name = 'ADMIN'
AND    user_id = **USER ID #s**;

COMMIT;
```

********************************Unlock User*******************************

```
BEGIN
  WWV_FLOW_SECURITY.g_security_group_id := 10;
  WWV_FLOW_FND_USER_API.unlock_account('ADMIN');
  COMMIT;
END;
/
```

But this has not worked, I still get the message that the account is locked.

I also tried to go to this table in the Database:

```
WWV_FLOW_FND_USER
```

to change it manually but that didn't work either.

What else can I do?

NOTE: I got no errors when running these scripts.

Comment: Is this the instance administrator account, or a workspace account? Either way, there are APEX API calls for changing passwords; this is not something you should do directly with an `update` command.

Comment: The account that I'm trying to get back to is the Instance account. Is there any possible way around this?

Comment: Could you post a screenshot which shows how that "locked admin account" looks like? For example, Apex login page, or ... I don't know, wherever you noticed that it is locked. BTW, I sincerely doubt that you can - nowadays - change any Oracle password by updating some table. Passwords aren't stored as *text*, so I'd say that what you did was in vain.

Answer (score 0):

This solution works to update the Internal Instance Password, as required.

Within sqldeveloper, as I was using, I had to make sure I had my Production connection set as I was trying to accomplish the desired result in my test environment.